# Azure publish profile - How to add SkipExtraFilesOnServer to an existing app

Tags: azure, deployment

I am having some trouble with an extension not working every time we deploy an app.
The vendor suggested we add  to the publish profile of the web app in question.
In the azure portal I can see how to download the profile and how to reset the profile.
But how do I change the existing publish profile?

Answer (score 0):

I actually found a better way to fix this. In the build powershell script that I use to deploy to azure, I added -enableRule:DoNotDeleteRule to the msdeploy parameters. That fixed it.